# How to convert factor column in df to numeric strings per row?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, factors

I am using R for a research project that requires me to input a sequence of 1-5 of varying length and then calculate a score from that sequence.

The data frame I have stores the sequences as a factor. If I take a single entry and convert it to a numeric vector, I can input it into the formula. But if I try to do this for all rows I run into errors.

I have searched SO and other sources but only found information on how to convert factors to numeric if they contain one value per cell. My data contains a sequence of numbers per cell separated by commas. 
If I take input from one cell and use as.numeric(strsplit(as.character it works. But I don't want to do all cells manually. How can I solve this?

This is what I did:

```
df <- read.csv2("example_seq_logs.csv", na.strings = "n/a")
df$seqtext <- as.character(df$hmm)
```

This is what the data frame looks like:

```
head(df)
  lesson                                       hmm
1      A 1,2,3,3,3,4,3,4,5,4,4,5,5,2,2,1,2,3,4,2,3
2      B           2,2,3,4,1,1,3,3,3,5,5,4,4,4,2,1
3      C 1,3,1,3,2,3,2,2,3,3,4,1,3,2,3,3,5,4,4,3,3
4      D       1,3,2,2,3,3,2,3,1,4,4,5,5,2,4,4,4,3
5      E                 1,4,2,5,1,3,1,3,1,4,3,4,4
str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ lesson: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ hmm   : Factor w/ 5 levels "1,2,3,3,3,4,3,4,5,4,4,5,5,2,2,1,2,3,4,2,3",..: 1 5 2 3 4
sapply(df, mode)
   lesson       hmm 
"numeric" "numeric"
```

Now if I take a single entry I can do this:

```
testseq <- as.numeric(strsplit(df$seqtext)[1],",")[[1]])
str(testseq)
 num [1:21] 1 2 3 3 3 4 3 4 5 4 ...
```

and then I can input the testseq sequence into the function I need. 
But when I try the same for the whole column it results in an error

```
df$seq <- as.numeric(strsplit(df$seqtext, ","))[[1:58]]
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Thank you for your help!

Edit: 
The first suggestion yields this error:

```
df$seq <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(paste(df$seqtext, collapse = ","), ",")))
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, seq, value = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3,  : 
  replacement has 89 rows, data has 5
```

It seems it turns the entire column into one long string.

```
a <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(paste(df$seqtext, collapse = ","), ",")))
print(a)
 [1] 1 2 3 3 3 4 3 4 5 4 4 5 5 2 2 1 2 3 4 2 3 2 2 3 4 1 1 3 3 3 5 5 4 4 4 2 1 1 3 1 3 2 3 2 2 3 3 4 1 3 2 3
[53] 3 5 4 4 3 3 1 3 2 2 3 3 2 3 1 4 4 5 5 2 4 4 4 3 1 4 2 5 1 3 1 3 1 4 3 4 4
```

But I need each sequence to turn up in the right row as a string.

Edit:
I found that the function I need to calculate results with doesn't need numerics so now I've solved the issue using a for loop:

```
df$score <- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  seq <- as.array(strsplit(as.character(df$hmm),","))
  session_seq <- seq[i]
  res = computehmm(session_seq)
  df$score[i] <- res$score
}
```

But now it stops calculating once it reaches an empty df$hmm field.

I understand sapply would be better but I don't understand how to get it to work.

Comment: Would be helpful to those helping if you shared your data in a reproducible form and be clearer about the expected output.

Comment: Do you mean to upload the csv somewhere? I assumed showing the data frame would be clear. The expected output would be a score for each row calculated from the sequence with the computehmm function, inserted into the data frame. I can add the code for the computehmm function if it's helpful, but I don't think the issue is in there and it's a lot of lines. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paste` as:

```
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(paste(df$seqtext, collapse = ","), ",")))
```

Comment: That seems to turn all the data in the seqtext column into one string. I need to have each string in its own cell.

Comment: Then you should use `sapply`